# df.loc more than 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "B": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 
600]})
```

And I want to create a new column with some value if certain conditions are met. The problem is: These are multiple conditions with `&` and `|`. I know I can do this with only two conditions and then multiple `df.loc` calls, but since my actual dataset is quite huge with many different values the variables can take, I'd like to know if it is possible to do this in one `df.loc` call. I also tried `np.where` before, but found `df.loc` generally easier so it would be nice if I can stick with it.

The code I tried is

```
df.loc[(df.A == 1) | (df.A == 2) & (df.B == 600) | (df.B == 200), "C"] = 
"1or2and600or200"
```

which gives me

```
print(df)  
   A    B                C
0  1  100  1or2and600or200
1  2  200  1or2and600or200
2  3  300              NaN
3  4  400              NaN
4  5  500              NaN
5  6  600              NaN
```

This however is not what I want, as `df.loc` likely only considers the first two conditions. So, I would want, in this code example, the value `1or2and600or200` to be only in the first line, not in the second one. Is this possible?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

All good, except you need to take care of extra parenthesis.

```
df.loc[((df.A == 1) | (df.A == 2)) & ((df.B == 600) | (df.B == 200)), "C"] = "1or2and600or200"
```

You can also proceed with `.isin` for more clear and concise picture as referred by @AndrewF

```
df.loc[df.A.isin([1, 2]) & df.B.isin([600, 200]), 'C'] = "1or2and600or200"
```

Also, for your given condition, it will be present in second row, because it's where you have `200` in `B`

Comment: Just a small note that OP could also use [`.isin(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to have slightly cleaner conditions. I.e. `df.A.isin([1, 2]) & df.B.isin([600, 200])`

Comment: Both approaches work perfectly and are so simple. Thank you so much, this helps me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have it in the first line as the value for B in the first line is 100 and not 200. As per your requirement, the code could be in the following way:

```py
df.loc[(df['A'].isin([1,2])) & (df['B'].isin([100])),'C'] = "1or2and600or200"
```

`isin()` is quite useful in case of multiple conditions.

Comment: It is better to have all "code" or, in other words, "non-English text" to be inside a code block. This increases clarity.